# Invalid certificate with Dynamic Domain

Tags: networking, ssl, certificate, dynamic-dns, nextcloud

What I tried to do:
Set up a Dynamic domain to connect with my Nextcloud(Self data storing) which is hosted on my home server.

What has been done:
Bought domain at domain.google.com
Setted up Dynamic DNS
Installed ddclient on my server
Connected ddclient with Google(The Dynamic DNS pointed to my server)
Server firewall has port 443 and 80 open
Router forwards port 80 and 443 to my server\

When I tip the domain into my Browser(Firefox and Brave)
This warning comes up.\

```
NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
```

Pressing on this error gives something like this

```
Subject: $my_servers_name
Issuer: $my_servers_name
Expires on: 10 Jul 2023
Current date: 29 Aug 2022
PEM encoded chain:-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
```

And two different certificates
This website: [https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/\](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/%5C)
When entering my domain it prints that `Certificate name mismatch` and I should try these other domains `$my_server_name`
Since the website and the browser got my servers name, there has to be some connection, but the certificates don’t match up.
What should I do.
$my_server_name is not my servers name, just a place holder

Comment: What does _Since the website and the browser got my servers name, there has to be some connection,_ mean?

Comment: They got my server name. The website showed it to me via the alternative link and it was the certificate subject

Comment: So I have to change the SAN so it looks like the_url.com and make sure my browser trust the certificate signer? How can I do that and when I buy the domain at Google, didn’t they sign it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two things for this to work:

1. You need a certificate that is trusted by your browser.  That means obtaining one from a commercial CA (such as Lets Encrypt) or adding your own CA to the browser's trust anchor store.  The former would mean all devices would be able to access your site.  The latter means the certificate only works for your device(s).  That is, you have to add the certificate to all devices which need to access your Nextcloud service.
2. You need to change the SAN in your certificate so that it contains the [host part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260218/parts-of-a-url-host-port-path) of the URL. E.g., `superuser.com` is the hostname of this site, so the certificate for this site will have that name in its SAN.  Google provides you with a DNS name, not a CA. Your example above shows that the issuer is *$my_server_name* which definitely isn't Google.